# Is it possible to change site type?

Tags: 2010, site-template

Let's say I have a wiki site that contains some text that I want to change into a publishing site. Is this possible? And if the answer is yes how would I go about doing it?

The problem I'm having is that a lot of Wiki sites were created when they infact should have been Publishing sites. Activating the Publishing feature on a Wiki site doesn't give me the functionalty I need, like the option to Publish a site or to change the Page Layout. Some sites also contains some web parts aswell as text, so I'm guessing I'll have to create a new Publishing site and then copy the text over and recreate the web parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I think you'll have to do that manually. Of course, it's possible to enable the Publishing feature on your site, but I'm not sure if that'll suit your needs.

Comment: Any ideas on my problem?

Comment: I think you need to recreate the site, yes. There are some options via PowerShell or console app of course, but I doubt it's worth it unless the number of pages are huge.

Comment: If you know where I could find any PS scripts or console apps or any pointers on how to this I'd greatly appreciate it as I've been finding more and more wiki sites all over the place.

Comment: Here's what I'm thinking, but I have not done this myself so I won't guarantee it's working.

Loop through each listitem in your wiki site library (SitePages). The content of the pages is in the listitems "WikiField" field. You will now have to get the content of this wiki page, and massage the data. e.g. links will probably have to be redone to work outside wikis, and some divs and tables might not make sense anymore.

For each wikipage create a new publishing page in another web and insert the data. Note: This will probably require some QA after th job has been done anyway.